# .NET: shutdown laptop even after close of application

Tags: .net, shutdown

## Update

### Situation:

I'm trying to make an application that shutdown my laptop using a simple button but when I press the button the shutdown still has to work.

### Question:

Is this possible to do? And how do I have to do it? Or is this an automatic process?

### Code:

I think the code should look like this:

```
    Private sub 
        Button1_click(ByVal...)
               Shell("shutdown /s") 
    End sub
```

Can someone please give me feedback if I used it correct?

**Thank You**

Comment: Are you trying to use C# or VB.net ? Can you post what you already tried ?

Comment: What programming language are you going to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To *restart* or *shutdown* your computer via *.net* you should use process.start to run your command:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start
```

In this case you need to run the *shutdown* command for example this option will restart your computer after a 30 second delay.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("ShutDown", "/r");
```

**Update to answer adicional questions:**

- If you want to change the *delay* you should use the *parameter* `/t x` (x in seconds), for example `/t 60` would delay the shutdown in 60 *seconds*.
- The computer will still shutdown after you close the application, to *abort* the shutdown execute the command `shutdown -a` in *cmd*

**More information about the shutdown command:**

> http://www.computerhope.com/shutdown.htm

Comment: Is it possible to delay the shutdown more than 30 seconds?

Comment: Yes use the /t parameter. for example /t 60 for 60 seconds.

Comment: Yes I see, and I should always express it in seconds? So if I use /t 120 it will be delayed 2 minutes?
And what about closing? If I close the form/application does the shutdown aborts or is it still counting down?

Comment: Just updated my answer to address your new questions, yes /t 120 will delay the shutdown in 2 minutes. And the shudown will still counting down, you need to execute a command to abort (explained in my answer)

Comment: Oh ok! Thank you :)
That was what I need!
If I could vote I would vote, but I can't, I'm sorry.
But still Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

You could just create a windows shortcut that executes:

```
shutdown -s -t 0
```

Or if you want to do this from C# (for example), have your C# program execute this:

```
Process.Start("shutdown","-s -t 0");
```